# jQuery .ajax and .appendTo in IE8

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, cross-browser

I am seeing strange behavior when opening the following page in various browsers:

```
<html>
    <head>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $.ajax({
                        url: "http://development.collegian.com/2013/06/27/newspaper-racks-looking-thin-on-campus/",
                        cache: false,
                        success: function(result) {
                            var test = $($.parseHTML(result));
                            test.appendTo("body");
                        }
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        Test.
    </body>
</html>
```

This works as expected (loads the specified URL) in Firefox and IE10, but when I turn on IE8 browser mode and IE8 Standards in the IE developer tools, the AJAX page does not load. No errors are thrown in IE.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

in ie 8 write full url

```
url: "http://development.collegian.com/2013/06/27/newspaper-racks-looking-thin-on-campus/index.php(or any full page name(home.html/home.php)

^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^set your file name here
```

**because in IE lower version it take full url**

Comment: Sorry, that doesn't work. I've tried outputting the result from the ajax function using `console.log(result)` and it appears to be good. I think where IE8 is tripping up is on the `appendTo()` call.